# Upload file from my laptop to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I am trying to upload file from my laptop to ec2 instance.

I am trying with this:

```
$ scp -i ec2_instance_key.pem ~/WebstormProjects/RESTAPI/config.js ec2-user@ec2-xxx.eu-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:~/data/
```

When I launch the command, terminal responses with:

```
scp: /home/ec2-user/data/: Is a directory
```

But I put it in ec2 terminal:

```
$ cd /home/ec2-user/data
```

And it responses with `no such file or directory`

And it copies file in my laptop again, in ec2-instance-key path.

What is the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The problem is that data is a existing path or something like that, because I launch the same command without data and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable case is :

- There is no directory named **data** in home directory of `ec2-user`.
- OR a file named **data** is mistakenly created in home directory, while doing `scp`.

Solution :

- Check if there exist a file named `data` at home directory of `ec2-user`.
- Move the file `~/data` to some other name(if exist).
- Create a directory named `data` in home directory of `ec2-user`.
- Give proper access permissions to the newly created `data` directory. (`chmod 644 ~/data`).
- Try uploading the file again by using following command :

  scp -i ec2_instance_key.pem ~/WebstormProjects/RESTAPI/config.js ec2-user@ec2-xxx.eu-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:~/data